# llenar un textbox derecha a izquierda vb.net

Tags: vb.net

he creado un programa que maneja precios y me es muy importante que todos lo usuarios manejes el mismo formato de precios.
Me gustaria hacer un codigo que vaya escribiendo en un textbox que automaticamente vaya escribiendo de derecha a izquierda e insertando la coma y los puntos separadores de miles, lo he intentado con un masked textbox pero no me arroja las catidades como realmente las necesito.
Necesito algo como van marcando las cantidades los cajeros automaticos

Comment: ¿Si te funcionó?

Comment: no me funcionó, se vuelve loco con las cantidades, me explico mejor supongamos que el valor inicial del textbox sea 0,00 al presionar 1 el textbox deberia ser 0,01, luego al presionar el dos el textbox seria 0,12. y si lo que quiero es poner 12.000,00 en el textbox presionaria el resto de ceros hasta que se complete.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es marcar como **Yes** la propiedad **RightToLeft** del textbox para que aparezca de derecha a izquierda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el formato de numero utiliza el siguiente código

```
texbox1.text = Format(TotalVenta, "$ #,###,##0.00")
```